# PostMessage Read Iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I have requirement where i need to get content of iframe where src is of another domain below is my code

```
<iframe id="receiver" src="http://demos.mattwest.io/post-message/receiver.html" width="500" height="200">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>



<script>
setTimeout(function(){ 
console.log($('#receiver').contents().find('body'));
 }, 2000);
```

I got following error

```
jquery-2.2.4.js:3079 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "http://demos.mattwest.io".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

I Searched a lot and found about PostMessage http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage

Here they are sending message and my goal is to get iframe content how can i implement postMessage in my sceneario.

I cant able to create fiddle, its showing some other issue https://jsfiddle.net/alokranjan39/re6aja0c/

How to resolve this please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

`postMessage` on an **iframe** will not work locally . You will need to **run this code on a server** or a test website that begins with `http` not `file` .

otherwise **avoid jQuery** because it uses postMessage() method inside `.contents()` to communicate with iframes .

**Pure javascript way :**

use `.contentDocument`

```
var iframer = document.getElementById('reciever');

var iframeBody = iframer.contentDocument.body;
```

**use case :**

```
iframer.contentDocument.getElementById('someElementInIframe')
```

ect...

Hope this helps

Comment: still getting same error i put the code in wamp www folder.if i am going to put my code in server what will be steps to implement postmessage and receive same result